# Error in allocating shared memory

Tags: c, shared-memory

I am trying to allocate a shared memory of size 64B. But the compiler throws error when i give a size of more than 27.. How to solve this problem. I am using gcc compiler. I am running the program on a server.

This is the code i used.

```
 shmid=(shmget(key,size,IPC_CREAT | 0666));   // size is defined as 64
```

I am getting an error saying memory allocation failed. But for size under 27 it works fine

Comment: Can you give us a **complete** example which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use SysV shared memory -- the interface is seriously awful, and has a number of huge drawbacks (e.g, there are tight limits on how much you can use, and it has to be cleaned up manually if your application crashes). If you need shared memory, use `mmap()`.